# Population with 1 or more successes

Tags: distributions

I have limited knowledge in statistics, please bear with me!

I am trying to develop a model based on the following conditions:

- I have a finite population `P` to draw from, essentially between 1 and 10 billions
- I draw an element from that population
- the element has a probability of being successful `S`
- regardless of the outcome, the element goes back to the population (population with replacement)
- I draw another element and repeat the same process until I've drawn `N` elements from the population

The goal is to know the number of elements that have been successful at least once.

The number of draws will be quite high so as far as I understand I will need to use a distribution and not a formula that would need to be computed for each individual draw.

At first, I wanted to use a binomial distribution but I realized that I double-count successes: if the same element gets drawn multiple times and is successful multiple times it is double-counted. Is there a way to take into account double-counting with that distribution?

I also looked at the beta binomial distribution but I failed to see how to would work for my situation. Same thing with the hypergeometric distribution.

Is there a good solution for my model? Or at least an approximation that would fit?

Comment: Is knowing the number of distinct selected successful elements really what you want, or is it an estimate of the number of successes in the population?

Comment: Some more context to it: this model focuses on replicating how a virus spreads.

I know that `s` people are sick and they have been in contact with `c` people. The `c` population overlaps since two different sick people can be in contact with the same person. The odds of contracting the virus is `o`.

I want to know how many people will contract the disease.

I pick `s * c` people from my population `P` and I run a test having an `o` probability of success to see if they are infected or not. After the draw that person goes back in the population as it can be picked again

Answer (score 3):

The binomial distribution is (exactly) correct, just as is.

Without replacement you'd have had a hypergeometric distribution.

Let's use a deck of cards as a model for your population (it would be a very big deck since you said it was in the billions). The deck contains red (diamonds, hearts) and black cards (clubs, spades) but not in equal numbers.

You want to estimate the proportion of red cards. There are n cards in the deck, $n_r$ red ones and $n_b$ black ones ($n_r+n_b=n$); you're interested in $p_r = n_r/n$. You shuffle the deck, draw a card, and examine it. You shuffle the drawn card back into the deck thoroughly and draw again. That's straight binomial sampling with probability of success $p_r=n_r/n$ and the sample proportion of red cards drawn with replacement is a suitable estimator of the parameter $p_r$.

[Each draw is a separate Bernoulli trial with constant probability of success and the trial outcomes are independent; the total number of successes in $m$ trials is therefore binomial.]

Yes, you can see the "same" red card again more than once. This is of no concern in estimating the proportion of red cards $-$ it's just a little less efficient than sampling without replacement and using the hypergeometric, but typically the sample size is far below the population size.

If $n$ is known, a suitable estimate of $n_r=n\cdot p_r$ can be obtained by scaling the estimate of $p_r$; that is if you drew $m$ cards with replacement, and $R=r$ were red, then a proportion $\hat{p}_r = r/m$ were red. In that case, $\hat{n}_r=n\, \hat{p}_r = \frac{nr}{m}$ is generally a suitable estimator of the number of reds in the population (it won't generally be an integer, though; if that matters, you can find a maximum likelihood estimator of $n_r$ instead, say by simply looking at the likelihood of possible $n_r$ either side of this simple estimator)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

The binomial distribution is then correct as long as the population is large enough compared to the number of draws.

Are there any possible approximations when this is not the case (number of draws close to the size of the population)?

In the first version of my model I used a binomial distribution as explained but I switch to individual draws when the central limit theorem starts to apply (this switching point is fairly arbitrary though and from a computation point of view this is inefficient).

Comment: No, to clarify, the binomial is correct even if the population is small relative to the number of draws. You could have a population of 3 cards and do 100 draws, it would still be *exactly* binomial; draws are independent with constant probability, so it's always a sequence of Bernoulli trials. My mention of a very big deck was simply to match your own description of your problem (population of billions) so that you could see I wasn't changing the situation. Sorry if that misled you. I have clarified.